# Progress bar not synchronous with file upload in Android application

Tags: android, file, post, upload

I'm trying to upload a file via **POST** method in **Android** application with the following code and it works well. If I try to display a progress bar refreshed in the while body **(mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(sentBytes)**) I noticed that it's not synchronous with the file upload but it show percentage relative to write in **DataOutputStream**.
When the while block ends, the upload is really starting. It seems as the **DataOutputStream** first saves chunks in local, then upload them all in the end... but at that point, the progress bar is already completed. So it is like a fake progress bar.
Any ideas ?

```
 HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
 DataOutputStream dos = null;
 String lineEnd = "\r\n";
 String twoHyphens = "--";
 String boundary = "*****";
 int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
 byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;           

dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());                        


long fileSize = sourceFile.length();


bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];       
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  


int sentBytes = 0;
sentBytes += bytesRead;

     while (bytesRead > 0) {

          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                      // progressbar refreshed in Notification 
              mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(sentBytes);

              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                sentBytes += bytesRead;

                        }


                  dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                  dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);



                  serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                  String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                               + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
```

Comment: I guess you doing this inside an AsynTask

Comment: I'm running it in a thread started by Android service

Comment: Thought about using AsyncTask?

Comment: The question is that progressbar refreshing works, but display values written to the buffer (in the while body). When the buffer is written over the network, the progress bar is already completed.

Comment: Where in the line code above you closing the progressbar?

Comment: I'm refreshing progressbar here: mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(sentBytes);

Comment: Can you edit your source and add a comment where you doing that

Comment: done, you can find it now

Comment: mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(bytesRead); Try This

Comment: I've added setChunkedStreamingMode(8192); to the HttpsURLConnection object and it forces to transmit the chunks over the network on each DataOutputStream write.

@Terril Thomas thank you for the support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a UI problem, always use Log to debug the real value, in your case you fill a buffer, so I guess it's "too fast" to be visible on your progress bar.

I believed you must set

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
```

To send data "packet by packet" instead of fill the buffer, then send the whole buffer.